# Is segment plot available in qplot()?

Tags: r, ggplot2

http://sape.inf.usi.ch/quick-reference/ggplot2/geom_segment

The above examples only show how to do segment plot using ggplot(). How can I plot a segment plot using qplot?

Comment: `qplot(d$x, d$y, xend = d$x + d$vx, yend = d$y + d$vy, geom = 'segment', arrow = arrow(), size = I(2), color = I('blue'))`

Comment: But 1) that example is super outdated, and 2) `qplot` has been deprecated so I don't recommend actually using this. Use `ggplot` instead.

Comment: Why use ggplot? In many cases, qplot command is much shorter. Why one would prefer a longer command instead of a shorter command? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: See `?qplot`: _"qplot() is now deprecated in order to encourage the users to learn ggplot() as it makes it easier to create complex graphics."_